# Save Conflict Error while saving SPListItem

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, splistitem, eventhandler

I have one sharepoint 2010 application, in which i have to add the item to the list followed by 2 more updates within the same list item. These are the items that I have to do while saving.

1. I need to save the item into my parent list.
2. I have registered one event handler (Item Added event) which will trigger after step 1, and it will creates a new item into the task list.
3. After the first step, again i am updating the same list item column for saving an URL column with the Item ID
4. After the 2nd step. Ie Task Item added by the event handler, I need to update the Parent list column with the task list item ID

While doing these steps. I am getting Save Conflict error.

I tried to use the Reload the SpListItem and Thread.Sleep method too. But everything has failed.

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit I don't quite follow your steps but just wondering if you've tried the `ItemAdding` event instead, Added is asynchronous, so will fire after the item has been created which might be conflicting with your other code or user action.  Adding is synchronous which sounds more appropriate although I could be wrong.